# Reference request; fractional Laplacian; boundary regularity

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider $B_2^+$ the half ball in $R^N$ and consider
$ (-\Delta)^s u = f(x) $ in $B_2^+$  with $ u=0$ outside.   Is there any references where someone tries to use an odd extension of $u$ across $ x_N=0$ to obtain boundary regularity?  Looking at the optimal boundary regularity it appears that this trick will fail;  I am curious how it fails.

Comment: Well, it will fail because the resulting function doesn't solve the PDE on the original domain, since you've changed it far away and the equation is nonlocal. I would recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5985, which uses some basic barrier arguments to get optimal regularity and discusses the solution on a half-space along the way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and of course I aware of those papers but I have never looked at details in them (I have read the results).   But i will look at the half space stuff since it will give me some much needed insight. The reason i asking is about trying an odd reflection  with a fractional term and a $ \Delta$;  but i guess there is no hope of that giving much.  thanks